# Java Radomly Generating Numbers Error

Tags: java, random

I am writing this code to run 10000000 times and randomly generate a number and pick the most oftenly generated number, but the results do not seem random. The I have written is

```
public class Randomizer {
    public static int[][] numbers = new int[45][2];
    public static int maxN = 0;
    public static int finalChoice;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arithmoi[] = new int[5];
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
            arithmoi[i] = randomizer(1000000, 45);
            System.out.println("A "+i+": "+arithmoi[i]);
        }
        int extra_num = randomizer(1000000, 20);
        System.out.println("\nT: "+extra_num);


    }

    public static int randomizer(int times, int amount){
        int[][] numbers = new int[amount][2];
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            numbers[i][0] = i + 1;
            numbers[i][1] = 0;          
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < times; i ++){
            int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * amount + 1);
            for(int j = 0; j < amount; j++){
                if(rnd == numbers [j] [0]){
                    numbers[j][1] ++ ;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            if(maxN < numbers[i][1]){
                finalChoice = numbers[i][0];
                maxN = numbers[i][1];
            }           
        }
        return finalChoice;

    }



}
```

The result that it gives me are A 0: 36
A 1: 36
A 2: 36
A 3: 36
A 4: 29

T: 14, A 0: 26
A 1: 44
A 2: 44
A 3: 44
A 4: 44

T: 4
 and similar. What could the problem be?

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Randomizer {
    public static int[][] numbers = new int[45][2];
    public static int maxN = 0;
    public static int finalChoice;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arithmoi[] = new int[5];
        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
            arithmoi[i] = randomizer(1000000, 45);
            System.out.println("A "+(i+1)+": "+arithmoi[i]);
        }
        int extra_num = randomizer(1000000, 20);
        System.out.println("\nT: "+extra_num);


    }

    public static int randomizer(int times, int amount){
        int[][] numbers = new int[amount][2];
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            numbers[i][0] = i + 1;
            numbers[i][1] = 0;          
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < times; i ++){            
            int rnd = randomGenerator.nextInt(amount);
            for(int j = 0; j < amount; j++){
                if(rnd == numbers [j] [0]){
                    numbers[j][1] ++ ;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            if(maxN < numbers[i][1]){
                finalChoice = numbers[i][0];
                maxN = numbers[i][1];
            }           
        }
        return finalChoice;

    }



}
```

The new code has still the same results(I used the Random Class)

Comment: Is there any reason you did not use `Random`?

Comment: Still not random after some tests I did using the Random method

Comment: Your data structure is, um, odd.  You know (from the definition of nextInt) that you will get back random values between 0 and amount (not including amount).  Create a single dimension array of size amount and just do numbers[randomGenerator.nextInt(amount)++;

Answer (score 0):

You should use Java's Random class (java.util.Random) instead of writing your own. It is written by experts and has improved over many years as it is used and therefore tested by millions. It has been proven to generate pseudo-random numbers that do not have any particular pattern.

Writing your own pseudo-random generator would not be straight forward as there are a lot of factors involved.

Here is an example of its use:

```
Random random = new Random();
int maxIterations = 10000000;
int maxRandomValue = 100;

for(int i=0; i< maxIterations; i++)
{ 
    System.out.println("Next random value: " + random.nextInt(maxRandomValue));
}
```

Comment: I am not using my own random number generaton, I use Math.random for that. Using the Random has the same results

Comment: You should use java.util.Random, not java.Math.Random.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem of you code it the way you tired to solve the task.
First of `int[][] numbers = new int[amount][2];` holds redundant information because `numbers[*][0]` hold the position. Since `numbers[i][1]` holds the result for position `i + 1` you can reduce the structure to `int[amount]`. 
Unlike other languages java defines the initial state of an `int` array to be always zero, so you do not need the first loop.

Your task is to let it rain on a line and check after n rounds, how many raindrops hit a certain spot/position.

It is okay to loop n times but since `rnd.nextInt(amount)` already gives you the spot the raindrop landed on, you do not have to iterate to find it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
   number[rnd.nextInt(amount)]++;
}
```

This will simulate the raindrops, but to get the proper random, you should initialize `private static Random rnd = new Random()` at class level and not at method level.

I hope this will help to solve your task.